# COUNTIF returns 0

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

In Excel I am using `COUNTIF` to count the value TRUE in one certain column. However, it does work while calculations are made in another column, but not in this one. The cellproperties are exactly the same.

Column D returns TRUE or FALSE by doing this calculation:

```
=IF(A7>B7;"TRUE";"FALSE")
```

Now I want to count the amount that TRUE occurs, and I use this calculation:

```
=COUNTIF(D:D;"TRUE")
```

Which returns 0.

Do `IF` and `COUNTIF` not work together if they are used in seperate cells? What am I doing wrong? It seems so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating text strings that look like TRUE/FALSE. The COUNTIF resolves quoted equations to a result so in the COUNTIF, `=countif(d:d, "TRUE")` is the same as `=countif(d:d, TRUE)`.

Change the formula in D:D to produce true boolean results,

```
=IF(A7>B7; TRUE; FALSE)
'alternate
=A7>B7
```

Use either of these,

```
=COUNTIF(D:D; TRUE)
=COUNTIF(D:D; "TRUE")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the COUNTIF function currently counts cells which contain the boolean value TRUE, not cells containing the TEXT "TRUE". This happens to be the way the COUNTIF function works. To avoid the problem, change your first formula to a simple:

```
=A7>B7
```